# SwiftUI: Why does the changed property of my Data not refresh the UI?

Tags: swift, swiftui, observedobject

I have the following data model:

```
class MyImage: : Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {
    let id = UUID()

    var path: String
    @Published var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D?
}

class MyImageCollection : ObservableObject {
    @Published var images: [MyImage] = []
    @Published var selection: Set<UUID> = []

}

extension Array where Element == MyImage {
    func haveCoordinates() -> Array<MyImage> {
        return filter { (image) -> Bool in
            return image.coordinate != nil
        }
    }
}
```

I use the collection in the views as follows:

```
# Top View

@StateObject var imageModel: MyImageCollection = MyImageCollection()

# Dependend Views

@ObservedObject var imageModel: MyImageCollection
```

So in my SwiftUI, whenever I add a new instance of MyImage via `imageCollection.images.append(anImage)`  everything works perfectly and any View is updated accordingly, also any View using `imageCollection.haveCoordinates()` is updated. But I also want to have any views updated, when I change a property of an image like `imageCollection.images[0].coordinate = someCoordinate`. That does not work currently.

Any hints?

Answer (score 0):

Your subviews need to directly observe your 'MyImage' class to be updated accordingly. Pass in your 'MyImage' instances directly into an observed object variable.  Here's what that may look like...

```
ForEach(collection.images) { myImage in
   YourSubView(image: myImage)
}
```

Where the image parameter is passed to an observed object property in your subview.

Answer (score 0):

Switch the `@ObservedObject` to `@EnvironmentObject` in the `DependantView` and initialize `DependentView().environmentObject(imageModel)`. [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app).This connects the two instances.

Also, If you want to Observe each `MyImage` you have to create an `MyImageView` that observes it directly

```
struct MyImage: View{
    @ObservedObject var myImage: MyImage
    //Rest of code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your replies, very appreciated. I was trying to create a Subview with a reference to the object as ObservableObject too, but failed because I was using `MapAnnotation` and that is initialized with the `coordinate` property. Need to figure that out in detail what the difference is here, the documentation from Apple does not help very much to see any difference at a glance. I'm using some kind of workaround now by "invalidating" the MyImage instance with setting a new UUID:

```
class MyImage: : Identifiable, Equatable, ObservableObject {
    var id = UUID()

    var path: String
    @Published var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D? {
        didSet {
            id = UUID()
        }
    }
}
```